# Docker - using labels to influence the start-up sequence

Tags: docker, dockerfile, celery, traefik, docker-entrypoint

My Django application uses Celery to process tasks on a regular basis. Sadly this results in having 3 continers (App, Celery Worker, Celery Beat) each of them having a very own startup shell-script instead of a docker entrypoint script.
So my Idea was to have a single entrypoint script which is able to process the lables I enter at my docker-compose.yml. Based on the lables the container should start as App, Celery Beat or Celery Worker instance.
I never did such a Implementation before but asking myself if this is even possible as I saw something similar at the trafik loadblancer project, see e.g.:

```
  loadbalancer:
    image: traefik:1.7
    command: --docker
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=false"
      - "traefik.docker.network=frontend"
      ...
```

I didn't found any good material according to that on the web or on how to implement such a scenario or if it's even possible the way I think here. Does smb did it like that befor or should I better stay with 3 single shell scripts, one for each service?

Comment: Honest question, why don't you simply create your own containers by extending the Celery Worker and Celery Beat containers with your own custom shell scripts as startup scrips? That would ensure you had a reproducible configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can access the labels from within the container, but it does not seem to be as straight forward as other options and I do not recommend it. See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439887/how-to-access-the-metadata-of-a-docker-container-from-a-script-running-inside-th).
2. If your use cases (== entrypoints) are more different than alike, it is probably easier to use three entrypoints or three commands.
3. If your use cases are more similar, then it is easier and clearer to simply use environment variables.
4. Another nice alternative that I like to use, it to create one entrypoint shell script, that accept arguments - so you have one entrypoint, and the arguments are provided using the `command` definition.

Labels are designed to be used by the docker engine and other applications that work at the host or docker-orchestrator level, and not at the container level.

Comment: Thanks for that information, really appreciate it. Give me a good point of view on how to further go on with my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the traefik project is using that implementation. If they use it, it should be totally possible.

**However**, I would recommend using environment variables instead of docker labels. Environment variables are the recommended way to processes configuration parameters in a cloud-native app. The use of the labels is more related to the service metadata, so you can identify and filter specific services. In your scenario you can have something like this:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  celery-worker:
    image: generic-dev-image:latest
    environment:
      - SERVICE_TYPE=celery-worker
  celery-beat:
    image: generic-dev-image:latest
    environment:
      - SERVICE_TYPE=celery-beat
  app:
    image: generic-dev-image:latest
    environment:
      - SERVICE_TYPE=app
```

Then you can use the `SERVICE_TYPE` environment variable in your docker entrypoint to launch the specific service.

**However** (again), there is nothing wrong with having 3 different docker images. In fact, that's the idea of containers (and microservices). You encapsulate the processes in images and instantiate them in containers. Each one of them will have different purposes and lifecycles. For development purposes, there is nothing wrong with your implementation. But in production, I would recommend separating the services in different images. Otherwise, you have big images, only using a third of the functionality in each service, and hard coupling the livecycle of the services.

Comment: So from what I understood here i should design my start.sh or entry-piint script so check for a env. var. well that also makes sense. Thanks for your Intention :D